# Will the pointer to a template member function inside a constructor force instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, instantiation, explicit

Consider the following header file:

```
// Foo.h
class Foo {
    public: template <typename T> void read(T& value);
};
```

It seems that assigning a pointer to `Foo::read<T>` in the constructor of a class, of which variable is then declared, cause instantiation:

```
// Foo.cc
#include "Foo.h"

template <typename T>
void Foo::read(T& value) { /* do something */ }

template <typename T> struct Bar {
    Bar<T>() { void (Foo::*funPtr)(T&) = &Foo::read<T>; }
};

static Bar<int  > bar1;
static Bar<long > bar2;
static Bar<float> bar3;
```

Is this solution reliable / portable / standard-conformant? (It works at least with Intel and GNU compilers.)

If you wonder why not to simply use `template Foo::read<int>(int&);` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5715586/580083).

Comment: "Is this solution reliable / portable / standard-conformant?". I'm sorry. I can't find a problem statement in your question. How can there be a solution without a problem?

Comment: @Johannes: Sorry if it's not clear, please see the linked question for details. I simply don't know, if this "forced explicit instantiation" will work for all standard-compliant compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your solution is portable. Here is a different way

```
template <typename T, T> struct user { };
template <typename T> struct Bar {
    typedef user< void (Foo::*)(T&), &Foo::read<T> > user_type;
};
```

Now whenever `Bar<T>` is implicitly instantiated, it will implicitly instanitate `Foo::read<T>`. No object needs to be created.

Answer (score 2):

14.7.1 is where it's at. /2 says:

> Unless a function template
>   specialization has been explicitly
>   instantiated or explicitly
>   specialized, the function template
>   specialization is implicitly
>   instantiated when the specialization
>   is referenced in a context that
>   requires a function definition to
>   exist.

Just like calling a function, taking a member function pointer requires that the function is defined in the program (perhaps in another TU). I believe that's what "requires a function definition to exist" means, so this is what causes the instantiation.

There's also /9:

> An implementation shall not implicitly
>   instantiate a function template, a
>   member template, a non-virtual member
>   function, a member class or a static
>   data member of a class template that
>   does not require instantiation.

So the fact that GCC and Intel instantiate it suggests that everyone else should, since that which is not required is forbidden. Assuming everyone conforms, of course.

Answer (score 1):

When objects for `Bar<type>` are declared **with actual types then definitely, Yes;** it will instantiate `Foo::read<type>()`. However, it will be limited only to that function (say `Foo::write<type>()` will not be instantiated).

In other way, if you try something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct X
{
  Bar<T> b1;  // this is required but not sufficient to instantiate Foo::read<T>()
};
```

Then `Foo::read<int>()` will not be instantiated until you declare `X<int>`.

**Edit**:
In above example, directly declaring `Bar<int> b1;` (`int` instead of `T`) inside `X`  is also NOT sufficient. Its containing type `X<>` has to be instantiated with actual (i.e. non-template) type.